# Database text search design improvement in sql

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

I have following design in my legacy application in oracle for text search across the table columns. Need suggestions/improvement/new way technology to this solution.

I have following tables with columns

table_1

```
id | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 .... column_40
---+----------+----------+-------------------------- 
1  | value1   | value2   | value3
```

table_2

```
id | column_1 |... column_50
---+----------+-------------
1  | value11  |... value55
```

Both tables have the same id and trigger that runs on any changes and insert the `Id` into `table_3`.

table_3 only contains id column.

```
id
---
1
```

I have a DB scheduler which every 5 seconds and checks new row on `table_3`. If it finds record the take the id and does join between `table_1` and `table_2` and do some data manipulation, aggregation and insert them into `table_4`.

table_4

```
id | textcolumn 
---+---------------------------------
1  | value1 value2 value3 .. value100
```

The `textcolumn` contains all the column values in `table_1` and `table_2` as text value.

This column will be use in LIKE % query to perform text search on all columns value and returns the id.

I have 2 more schedulers which call sync index and optimize index on `textcolumn` index for every 5 seconds and 3 minutes respectively.

Currently the table_4 contains data around 800K, I need suggestions/improvements/new technology to the current solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to copy the data in order to index it.  A text index can be configured so that the content that is being indexed is only in the index, and not in a "global" table that holds a replica of your real tables.

As it currently stands, my reading of your description suggests three copies of the data:

- the original table(s)
- the big table with a copy of the data which you then indexed with a text index
- the text index itself

You don't need the second one.

Here's a guide on how to do a user datastore index to give a "google like" search across multiple tables in your database

https://youtu.be/yjEdL_DX5dU

In 23c, there will be native facilities to make this even easier.